# C toggling logic function not working as expected

Tags: c

I need a function to read in a schedule (that uses the values in `enum heatingScheduleEnum  {off, on };`) and display at what times the schedule has toggled between on and off. I have written a function to do this, but it does not work as expected - working only until the first time that the value is toggled on then off again. After this, it outputs that the schedule is being toggled off each time it is actually marked as being on.

I have worked mainly with Java and C++, but this is in C. The logic looks perfectly fine to me and I cannot see why it does not work.

The interpretTime function takes a time in minutes (0-1439 is a full day) and converts it into a string readable by humans.

My only thought on what could be causing this is the copious size of the array. But the lecturers provided the sample array itself, and they did get the project tested.

Thank you!

Here is the function:

```
char time[5];
int i, on, wasOn = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 1440; i++) {
    on = schedule[i];
    if (on != wasOn) {
        makeTimeStr(i, time);
        if(on) {
            printf("Heating turns on at %s\n", time);
        }
        else {
            printf("Heating turns off at %s\n", time);
        }
        wasOn = on;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Heating turns off at 03:00
Heating turns off at 03:01
Heating turns off at 03:02
Heating turns off at 03:03
Heating turns off at 03:04
Heating turns off at 03:05
Heating turns off at 03:06
Heating turns off at 03:07
Heating turns off at 03:08
Heating turns off at 03:09
Heating turns off at 03:10
Heating turns off at 03:11
Heating turns off at 03:12
Heating turns off at 03:13
Heating turns off at 03:14
Heating turns off at 03:15
Heating turns off at 03:16
Heating turns off at 03:17
Heating turns off at 03:18
Heating turns off at 03:19
Heating turns off at 03:20
Heating turns off at 03:21
Heating turns off at 03:22
Heating turns off at 03:23
Heating turns off at 03:24
Heating turns off at 03:25
Heating turns off at 03:26
Heating turns off at 03:27
Heating turns off at 03:28
Heating turns off at 03:29
Heating turns off at 03:30
Heating turns off at 03:31
Heating turns off at 03:32
Heating turns off at 03:33
Heating turns off at 03:34
Heating turns off at 03:35
Heating turns off at 03:36
Heating turns off at 03:37
Heating turns off at 03:38
Heating turns off at 03:39
Heating turns off at 03:40
Heating turns off at 03:41
Heating turns off at 03:42
Heating turns off at 03:43
Heating turns off at 03:44
Heating turns off at 03:45
Heating turns off at 03:46
Heating turns off at 03:47
Heating turns off at 03:48
Heating turns off at 03:49
Heating turns off at 03:50
Heating turns off at 03:51
Heating turns off at 03:52
Heating turns off at 03:53
Heating turns off at 03:54
Heating turns off at 03:55
Heating turns off at 03:56
Heating turns off at 03:57
Heating turns off at 03:58
Heating turns off at 03:59
Heating turns off at 04:00
Heating turns off at 04:01
Heating turns off at 04:02
Heating turns off at 04:03
Heating turns off at 04:04
Heating turns off at 04:05
Heating turns off at 04:06
Heating turns off at 04:07
Heating turns off at 04:08
Heating turns off at 04:09
Heating turns off at 04:10
Heating turns off at 04:11
Heating turns off at 04:12
Heating turns off at 04:13
Heating turns off at 04:14
Heating turns off at 04:15
Heating turns off at 04:16
Heating turns off at 04:17
Heating turns off at 04:18
Heating turns off at 04:19
Heating turns off at 04:20
Heating turns off at 04:21
Heating turns off at 04:22
Heating turns off at 04:23
Heating turns off at 04:24
Heating turns off at 04:25
Heating turns off at 04:26
Heating turns off at 04:27
Heating turns off at 04:28
Heating turns off at 04:29
Heating turns off at 04:30
Heating turns off at 04:31
Heating turns off at 04:32
Heating turns off at 04:33
Heating turns off at 04:34
Heating turns off at 04:35
Heating turns off at 04:36
Heating turns off at 04:37
Heating turns off at 04:38
Heating turns off at 04:39
Heating turns off at 04:40
Heating turns off at 04:41
Heating turns off at 04:42
Heating turns off at 04:43
Heating turns off at 04:44
Heating turns off at 04:45
Heating turns off at 04:46
Heating turns off at 04:47
Heating turns off at 04:48
Heating turns off at 04:49
Heating turns off at 04:50
Heating turns off at 04:51
Heating turns off at 04:52
Heating turns off at 04:53
Heating turns off at 04:54
Heating turns off at 04:55
Heating turns off at 04:56
Heating turns off at 04:57
Heating turns off at 04:58
Heating turns off at 04:59
Heating turns off at 05:00
Heating turns off at 05:01
Heating turns off at 05:02
Heating turns off at 05:03
Heating turns off at 05:04
Heating turns off at 05:05
Heating turns off at 05:06
Heating turns off at 05:07
Heating turns off at 05:08
Heating turns off at 05:09
Heating turns off at 05:10
Heating turns off at 05:11
Heating turns off at 05:12
Heating turns off at 05:13
Heating turns off at 05:14
Heating turns off at 05:15
Heating turns off at 05:16
Heating turns off at 05:17
Heating turns off at 05:18
Heating turns off at 05:19
Heating turns off at 05:20
Heating turns off at 05:21
Heating turns off at 05:22
Heating turns off at 05:23
Heating turns off at 05:24
Heating turns off at 05:25
Heating turns off at 05:26
Heating turns off at 05:27
Heating turns off at 05:28
Heating turns off at 05:29
Heating turns off at 05:30
Heating turns off at 16:00
Heating turns off at 16:01
Heating turns off at 16:02
Heating turns off at 16:03
Heating turns off at 16:04
Heating turns off at 16:05
Heating turns off at 16:06
Heating turns off at 16:07
Heating turns off at 16:08
Heating turns off at 16:09
Heating turns off at 16:10
Heating turns off at 16:11
Heating turns off at 16:12
Heating turns off at 16:13
Heating turns off at 16:14
Heating turns off at 16:15
Heating turns off at 16:16
Heating turns off at 16:17
Heating turns off at 16:18
Heating turns off at 16:19
Heating turns off at 16:20
Heating turns off at 16:21
Heating turns off at 16:22
Heating turns off at 16:23
Heating turns off at 16:24
Heating turns off at 16:25
Heating turns off at 16:26
Heating turns off at 16:27
Heating turns off at 16:28
Heating turns off at 16:29
Heating turns off at 16:30
Heating turns off at 16:31
Heating turns off at 16:32
Heating turns off at 16:33
Heating turns off at 16:34
Heating turns off at 16:35
Heating turns off at 16:36
Heating turns off at 16:37
Heating turns off at 16:38
Heating turns off at 16:39
Heating turns off at 16:40
Heating turns off at 16:41
Heating turns off at 16:42
Heating turns off at 16:43
Heating turns off at 16:44
Heating turns off at 16:45
Heating turns off at 16:46
Heating turns off at 16:47
Heating turns off at 16:48
Heating turns off at 16:49
Heating turns off at 16:50
Heating turns off at 16:51
Heating turns off at 16:52
Heating turns off at 16:53
Heating turns off at 16:54
Heating turns off at 16:55
Heating turns off at 16:56
Heating turns off at 16:57
Heating turns off at 16:58
Heating turns off at 16:59
Heating turns off at 17:00
Heating turns off at 17:01
Heating turns off at 17:02
Heating turns off at 17:03
Heating turns off at 17:04
Heating turns off at 17:05
Heating turns off at 17:06
Heating turns off at 17:07
Heating turns off at 17:08
Heating turns off at 17:09
Heating turns off at 17:10
Heating turns off at 17:11
Heating turns off at 17:12
Heating turns off at 17:13
Heating turns off at 17:14
Heating turns off at 17:15
Heating turns off at 17:16
Heating turns off at 17:17
Heating turns off at 17:18
Heating turns off at 17:19
Heating turns off at 17:20
Heating turns off at 17:21
Heating turns off at 17:22
Heating turns off at 17:23
Heating turns off at 17:24
Heating turns off at 17:25
Heating turns off at 17:26
Heating turns off at 17:27
Heating turns off at 17:28
Heating turns off at 17:29
Heating turns off at 17:30
Heating turns off at 17:31
Heating turns off at 17:32
Heating turns off at 17:33
Heating turns off at 17:34
Heating turns off at 17:35
Heating turns off at 17:36
Heating turns off at 17:37
Heating turns off at 17:38
Heating turns off at 17:39
Heating turns off at 17:40
Heating turns off at 17:41
Heating turns off at 17:42
Heating turns off at 17:43
Heating turns off at 17:44
Heating turns off at 17:45
Heating turns off at 17:46
Heating turns off at 17:47
Heating turns off at 17:48
Heating turns off at 17:49
Heating turns off at 17:50
Heating turns off at 17:51
Heating turns off at 17:52
Heating turns off at 17:53
Heating turns off at 17:54
Heating turns off at 17:55
Heating turns off at 17:56
Heating turns off at 17:57
Heating turns off at 17:58
Heating turns off at 17:59
Heating turns off at 18:00
Heating turns off at 18:01
Heating turns off at 18:02
Heating turns off at 18:03
Heating turns off at 18:04
Heating turns off at 18:05
Heating turns off at 18:06
Heating turns off at 18:07
Heating turns off at 18:08
Heating turns off at 18:09
Heating turns off at 18:10
Heating turns off at 18:11
Heating turns off at 18:12
Heating turns off at 18:13
Heating turns off at 18:14
Heating turns off at 18:15
Heating turns off at 18:16
Heating turns off at 18:17
Heating turns off at 18:18
Heating turns off at 18:19
Heating turns off at 18:20
Heating turns off at 18:21
Heating turns off at 18:22
Heating turns off at 18:23
Heating turns off at 18:24
Heating turns off at 18:25
Heating turns off at 18:26
Heating turns off at 18:27
Heating turns off at 18:28
Heating turns off at 18:29
Heating turns off at 22:00
Heating turns off at 22:01
Heating turns off at 22:02
Heating turns off at 22:03
Heating turns off at 22:04
Heating turns off at 22:05
Heating turns off at 22:06
Heating turns off at 22:07
Heating turns off at 22:08
Heating turns off at 22:09
Heating turns off at 22:10
Heating turns off at 22:11
Heating turns off at 22:12
Heating turns off at 22:13
Heating turns off at 22:14
Heating turns off at 22:15
Heating turns off at 22:16
Heating turns off at 22:17
Heating turns off at 22:18
Heating turns off at 22:19
Heating turns off at 22:20
Heating turns off at 22:21
Heating turns off at 22:22
Heating turns off at 22:23
Heating turns off at 22:24
Heating turns off at 22:25
Heating turns off at 22:26
Heating turns off at 22:27
Heating turns off at 22:28
Heating turns off at 22:29
Heating turns off at 22:30
Heating turns off at 22:31
Heating turns off at 22:32
Heating turns off at 22:33
Heating turns off at 22:34
Heating turns off at 22:35
Heating turns off at 22:36
Heating turns off at 22:37
Heating turns off at 22:38
Heating turns off at 22:39
Heating turns off at 22:40
Heating turns off at 22:41
Heating turns off at 22:42
Heating turns off at 22:43
Heating turns off at 22:44
Heating turns off at 22:45
Heating turns off at 22:46
Heating turns off at 22:47
Heating turns off at 22:48
Heating turns off at 22:49
Heating turns off at 22:50
Heating turns off at 22:51
Heating turns off at 22:52
Heating turns off at 22:53
Heating turns off at 22:54
Heating turns off at 22:55
Heating turns off at 22:56
Heating turns off at 22:57
Heating turns off at 22:58
Heating turns off at 22:59
Heating turns off at 23:00
Heating turns off at 23:01
Heating turns off at 23:02
Heating turns off at 23:03
Heating turns off at 23:04
Heating turns off at 23:05
Heating turns off at 23:06
Heating turns off at 23:07
Heating turns off at 23:08
Heating turns off at 23:09
Heating turns off at 23:10
Heating turns off at 23:11
Heating turns off at 23:12
Heating turns off at 23:13
Heating turns off at 23:14
Heating turns off at 23:15
Heating turns off at 23:16
Heating turns off at 23:17
Heating turns off at 23:18
Heating turns off at 23:19
Heating turns off at 23:20
Heating turns off at 23:21
Heating turns off at 23:22
Heating turns off at 23:23
Heating turns off at 23:24
Heating turns off at 23:25
Heating turns off at 23:26
Heating turns off at 23:27
Heating turns off at 23:28
Heating turns off at 23:29
Heating turns off at 23:30
Heating turns off at 23:31
Heating turns off at 23:32
Heating turns off at 23:33
Heating turns off at 23:34
Heating turns off at 23:35
Heating turns off at 23:36
Heating turns off at 23:37
Heating turns off at 23:38
Heating turns off at 23:39
Heating turns off at 23:40
Heating turns off at 23:41
Heating turns off at 23:42
Heating turns off at 23:43
Heating turns off at 23:44
Heating turns off at 23:45
Heating turns off at 23:46
Heating turns off at 23:47
Heating turns off at 23:48
Heating turns off at 23:49
Heating turns off at 23:50
Heating turns off at 23:51
Heating turns off at 23:52
Heating turns off at 23:53
Heating turns off at 23:54
```

And here is the schedule (provided by the univesity):

```
#define heatingScheduleTypicalValues  {off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , off , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , on , off , off , off , off , off }
```

Comment: You never referred to `heatingScheduleTypicalVaues`.

Comment: This is done in my main function. `int main() {
 char timeStr[5];
 heatingScheduleType heatingSchedule[1440] = heatingScheduleTypicalValues;

 setbuf(stdout, 0);

 interpretTime(65, timeStr); //Test interpretTime
 printf("%s\n", timeStr);

 printHeatingSchedule(heatingSchedule); //Test printHeatingSchedule

 return 0;
}`

Comment: What is the data type of `schedule[i]` i.e how `off`, `on` is stored?

Comment: @GauravSehgal - `enum heatingScheduleEnum  {off, on };
typedef enum heatingScheduleEnum heatingScheduleType;` It should be ints of 0 and 1.

Comment: `isOn = schedule[i];` Debug and see if `isOn` actually gets value `0` and `1`.My guess is no, because every time it goes to else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the parts of `schedule` into the right structure, not just `int`.

Also timestr is not quite long enough so some of your other variables might be  being overwritten by `interpretTime`

Comment: The enums (int) do very well, but your catch on `timeStr` being to small is nice. 1+ for this.

Comment: Thank you, the timeStr being too small was correct. Once I corrected it, my program started running properly. It was my mistake to assume that I did not have to account for the escape character when declaring the length of the string.

Comment: heatingScheduleType  is not the same as the enum heatingScheduleEnum   (and I'd argue using int/enum interchangeably is bad practice anyway)